# New user removed?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Someone was asking some good questions, about the possibility of the use of bribery in evangelization, and had evidence about poor rhetoric ("devil-worshippers") being addressed to non-Christians in evangelization. The person was also responding very positively to suggestions about how things could be better worded in future questions, even politely said you can close this question.

Q: Why was this person removed?

If this were a question-and-answer site, all signs were positive.  If this site were to have evangeliziation purpose, then perhaps it's good to keep those asking questions as to whether elements of Christianity's dark underbelly had any biblical basis.  (Hint: I think  a polite Q-and-A exchange about dark-underbelly facts is actually the best evangelization there is).

Answer (score 4):

Generally users are removed one of two ways:

- They delete their own account
- They ask SEI to delete their account.

This looks like a case of the first. The user had a single (or a couple?) posts that are now deleted and they've deleted their own account. It could also be the second, but that is less likely as there is typically a short waiting period when SEI deletes an account.

Comment: Thanks kindly for the information.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't looked into the the specifics of this case, but even if there turns out to be something to see, just so you know this isn't information that moderators can divulge. If the user made and left a public statement that we happened to know about, we could maybe point you to it, but for people that delete their accounts, their reasons are private.

In a few cases of blatant spam we will delete accounts, but never somebody that was actually trying to contribute however bad their contributions may be. If there is an issue with their contributions they might be suspended from posting privileges and individual posts might be removed, but deleting users accounts is not a tool used for moderation purposes.

If you see a deleted account (that was doing anything other more relevant than posting links to illegitimate medication sites), you can pretty much bet the user specifically requested deletion (or in the case of having few posts, were able to self-delete).